# Generate effective C/Java code (minimizing operations)

Tags: code-generation

Is it possible to generate C/Java code with Mathematica so that it minimizes number of operations performed? For example, for matrix inverse or determinant? With good caching variables?

Comment: Have a look at these answers about [``Experimental`OptimizeExpression``](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=OptimizeExpression). Not sure it will help much since both C compilers and java optimizes a bunch themselves.

Comment: The functionality you ask for is provided either by libraries like MKL which have highly optimized implementations for matrix operations, or by optimizing compilers, when you mean general language instructions rather than specific algorithms. Both are huge fields with a lot of domain-specific knowledge. Even if Mathematica could be used to write optimizers, this certainly doesn't look like a question which can be sensibly answered in the SE format. Also, the question is really to broad and lacks the focus, regardless of SE limitations.